# Pandas selecting rows based on bool values over a range of columns by position

Tags: pandas

I have a df

```
Name   Param_1   Param_2   Param_3
John   True      False     False 
Mary   False     False     False
Peter  True      False     False 
Linda  False     False     True
```

I want to create two new dataframes based on the `True` or `False` values across the range of colunms (`Params_1`, `Params_2` and `Params_3`). Something like this...

```
df_1 =
Name   Param_1   Param_2   Param_3
John   True      False     False
Peter  True      False     False
Linda  False     False     True

df_2 = 
Name   Param_1   Param_2   Param_3
Mary   False      False     False
```

however, I won't know the names of Param_1 etc. each time the code is run, so I want to use positinal indexing (slicing). In this case, `[:, 1:]`

I have seen examples of selecting rows based on the values within one column, when the column has a known name, but not by slicing across multiple columns by position.

I tried `ais_gdf.iloc[ais_gdf[:, 1:].isin(False)]` but that didn't work.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to get boolean columns. Create a mask and then use this mask to filter.

```
mask = (~df.select_dtypes(bool)).all(axis=1)
df1 = df[mask]

   Name  Param_1  Param_2  Param_3
1  Mary    False    False    False

df2 = df[~mask]

    Name  Param_1  Param_2  Param_3
0   John     True    False    False
2  Peter     True    False    False
3  Linda    False    False     True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select columns for mask and test if at least one `True` by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), for `df_2` invert mask by `~`:

```
m = ais_gdf.iloc[:, 1:].any(axis=1)
#alternative for select only boolean columns
#m = ais_gdf.select_dtypes(bool).any(axis=1)
#alternative1 for columns names with with Param
#m = ais_gdf.filter(like='Param').any(axis=1)
df_1 = ais_gdf[m]
df_2 = ais_gdf[~m]

print (df_1)
    Name  Param_1  Param_2  Param_3
0   John     True    False    False
2  Peter     True    False    False
3  Linda    False    False     True

print (df_2)
   Name  Param_1  Param_2  Param_3
1  Mary    False    False    False
```